# How to update gridview when upon click submit button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, autopostback

I want to add booth detail into database, after user insert booth alias, select booth type and booth duration, next click submit button and the newly added record will appear in the gridview below the old records.

[image]

I know there are something missing in the code but I not sure what is the problem.

The client code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageAdmin.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="addbooth.aspx.vb" Inherits="addbooth" title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server" 
contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder2">

 <table class="style8" cellpadding="3">
 <tr>
 <td class="style9">Add New Booth</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="style9">&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="style9">Event Title:</td>
 <td>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceEventTitle" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [eventID], [eventTitle] FROM [eventinfo]">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEventTitle" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceEventTitle" DataTextField="eventTitle" DataValueField="eventID" Width="240px" AutoPostBack="True">
 </asp:DropDownList>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="style9">Booth Alias:</td>
 <td>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoothAlias" runat="server" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="style9"> Booth Type:</td>
 <td>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBoothType" runat="server" Width="240px" AutoPostBack="True">
 <asp:ListItem Value="7">8&#39;x8&#39;</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="10">9&#39;x8&#39;</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="11">12&#39;x50&#39;</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="12">16&#39;x10&#39;</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="13">20&#39;x16&#39;</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="15">32&#39;x10&#39;</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="17">32&#39;x14.5&#39;</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="style10" valign="top" colspan="2">Booth Duration:<br />
 <font size="2">Tick to activate availability</font></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="style10" valign="top" colspan="2" align="center">
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="328px" Direction="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <table cellpadding="5" class="style8">
 <tr>
 <td>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="cbWeek1" runat="server" Text="Week 1" TextAlign="Left" OnCheckedChanged="cbWeek1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
  </td>
  <td>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="cbWeek2" runat="server" Text="Week 2" TextAlign="Left" OnCheckedChanged="cbWeek2_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
   </td>
   <td>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="cbWeek3" runat="server" Text="Week 3" TextAlign="Left" OnCheckedChanged="cbWeek3_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
   </td>
    <td>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="cbWeek4" runat="server" Text="Week 4" TextAlign="Left" OnCheckedChanged="cbWeek4_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                             <asp:CheckBox ID="cbWeek5" runat="server" Text="Week 5" TextAlign="Left" OnCheckedChanged="cbWeek5_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                              <asp:CheckBox ID="cbWeek6" runat="server" Text="Week 6" TextAlign="Left" OnCheckedChanged="cbWeek6_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                              <asp:CheckBox ID="cbWeek7" runat="server" Text="Week 7" TextAlign="Left" OnCheckedChanged="cbWeek7_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                              <asp:CheckBox ID="cbWeek8" runat="server" Text="Week 8" TextAlign="Left" OnCheckedChanged="cbWeek8_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>

  </asp:Panel>
  <asp:RoundedCornersExtender ID="Panel1_RoundedCornersExtender"runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Panel1" BorderColor="CadetBlue" Color="ButtonFace">
 </asp:RoundedCornersExtender>
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="style11">
         </td>
         <td class="style11">
 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddNewBooth" runat="server" Text="Add New Booth"  Height="50px" />
 </td>
 </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="style9"> &nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
         <tr>
 <td class="style9" colspan="2">
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewBoothAdded" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceBoothAdded" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" Visible="False">
 <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
 <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="boothAlias" HeaderText="Booth Alias" SortExpression="boothAlias" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="week1" HeaderText="week1" SortExpression="week1" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="week2" HeaderText="week2" SortExpression="week2" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="week3" HeaderText="week3" SortExpression="week3" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="week4" HeaderText="week4" SortExpression="week4" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="week5" HeaderText="week5" SortExpression="week5" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="week6" HeaderText="week6" SortExpression="week6" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="week7" HeaderText="week7" SortExpression="week7" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="week8" HeaderText="week8" SortExpression="week8" />
  </Columns>
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No booth record
  </EmptyDataTemplate>
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" />
  <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
   </asp:GridView>
   <asp:RoundedCornersExtender ID="GridViewBoothAdded_RoundedCornersExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="GridViewBoothAdded">
    </asp:RoundedCornersExtender>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceBoothAdded" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [week1], [week2], [week3], [week4], [week5], [week6], [week7], [week8], [eventID], [boothAlias], [eventTitle] FROM [booth_eventinfo] WHERE ([eventID] = @eventID)">
   <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEventTitle" Name="eventID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
   </SelectParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
   </table>
```

server code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Threading
Partial Class addbooth
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    GridViewBoothAdded.Visible = True
End Sub

Protected Sub ButtonAddNewBooth_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonAddNewBooth.Click
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
    '"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eventdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)

    Dim cmdQuery As String = "INSERT INTO booth(eventID,boothAlias,boothType,week1,week2,week3,week4,week5,week6,week7,week8) VALUES (@eventID,@boothAlias,@boothType,@week1,@week2,@week3,@week4,@week5,@week6,@week7,@week8)"

    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdQuery)
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventID", ddlEventTitle.SelectedValue)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@boothAlias", txtBoothAlias.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@boothType", ddlBoothType.SelectedValue)

    If (cbWeek1.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week1", "1")
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week1", "0")
    End If

    If (cbWeek2.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week2", "1")
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week2", "0")
    End If

    If (cbWeek3.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week3", "1")
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week3", "0")
    End If

    If (cbWeek4.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week4", "1")
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week4", "0")
    End If

    If (cbWeek5.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week5", "1")
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week5", "0")
    End If

    If (cbWeek6.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week6", "1")
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week6", "0")
    End If

    If (cbWeek7.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week7", "1")
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week7", "0")
    End If

    If (cbWeek8.Checked = True) Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week8", "1")
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@week8", "0")
    End If

    GridViewBoothAdded.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in your ButtonAddNewBooth_Click method you are missing the ExecuteSql() for the sqlcommand and gridview bind code

**After adding parameters to cmd add the following two lines one for executing the insert and the other for rebinding the grid**

```
cmd.ExecuteSql()

GridViewBoothAdded.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you move you GridView Data Binding Code to code behind file Page_Load Method & call the same code at the end of your ButtonAddNewBooth_Click event. That will serve your purpose.

Link: [GridView.DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx)